# Regexp negative look-behind ignored?

Tags: ruby, regex

In Ruby 2.0 Regexp, I'm hoping someone might be able to explain my error:

This positive look-behind is correct:

```
"seacow hotdog".scan(/(?<=hot)(cow|dog)/) # => [["dog"]]
```

This negative look-behind doesn't work:

```
"seacow hotdog".scan(/(?<!=hot)(cow|dog)/)  # => [["cow"], ["dog"]] - INCORRECT
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"seacow hotdog".scan(/(?<!=hot)(cow|dog)/)
                          ^
```

You have an `=` sign that shouldn't be there...

```
"seacow hotdog".scan(/(?<!hot)(cow|dog)/)
```

You were looking for `=hot` as a literal string...

See http://rubular.com/r/Oaa8ToL8jN for demo

Comment: The documentation is very clear about `?<!`: "`(?<!pat)` - Negative lookbehind assertion: ensures that the preceding characters do not match pat, but doesn't include those characters in the matched text"

Comment: @Ross - good to hear it. Do you need anything else, or does this answer your question?